# Dynamically created dropdown giving error on calling a method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my code, so basically on click of button I want to call this method addpoc() which creates a block of input boxes and a dropdown. I want to call a method showmail() on selection of dropdown option but it throws error. How can i fix it ?

```js
  function addpoc() { 
                let el;
                el += '<div class="clearfix"><div class="name"><label for="fname">First name:</label><br><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ricky"></div><div class="name"><label for="lname">Last name:</label><br><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ju"></div></div><div class="parent" style="width: 100%;"><div id="one"><select id="contact method" onchange="'+ showMail() +'"><option value="workmail" selected>Work email </option><option value="personalmail">Personal Email</option></select></div><div id="two" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Work email"></div><div id="three" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Personal email"></div></div>'

                $('#addelement').append(el);
            }
            
            
              function showMail() {
                let selecteop = document.getElementById("contact method");
                if (selecteop.value == "workmail") {

                    $("#two").show();
                    $("#three").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#three").show();
                    $("#two").hide();
                }
            }
```

```html
 <div>
                <div id="addelement"></div>
                <button id="addbtn" onclick="addpoc()">Add another point of contact</button>
           
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the `el += '<div cla ...` you were calling the `showMail` function before the whole element being inserted in the dom so `selecteop` was not created yet.

```js
 function addpoc() {
                let el;
                el += '<div class="clearfix"><div class="name"><label for="fname">First name:</label><br><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ricky"></div><div class="name"><label for="lname">Last name:</label><br><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ju"></div></div><div class="parent" style="width: 100%;"><div id="one"><select id="contact method" onchange="showMail()"><option value="workmail" selected>Work email </option><option value="personalmail">Personal Email</option></select></div><div id="two" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Work email"></div><div id="three" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Personal email"></div></div>'

                $('#addelement').append(el);
            }

            function showMail() {
                let selecteop = document.getElementById("contact method");
                if (selecteop.value == "workmail") {

                    $("#two").show();
                    $("#three").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#three").show();
                    $("#two").hide();
                }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <div id="addelement"></div>
      <button id="addbtn" onclick="addpoc()">Add another point of contact</button>  
 </div>
```

Comment: but it is not displaying the input box after the first time, on selection of personal/workmail dropdown option

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `function addpoc()` function as per below. Instead of calling function `showMail()` at the time of html creation just pass function reference to onChange like `onchange="'+ showMail +'"`  Just remove braces.
Also, initialize `el` to `''` empty. Otherwise, it will always start with `undefined`.  This will solve all your issues.

```
function addpoc() { 
    let el='';
    el += '<div class="clearfix"><div class="name"><label for="fname">First name:</label><br><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ricky"></div><div class="name"><label for="lname">Last name:</label><br><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ju"></div></div><div class="parent" style="width: 100%;"><div id="one"><select id="contact method" onchange="'+ showMail +'"><option value="workmail" selected>Work email </option><option value="personalmail">Personal Email</option></select></div><div id="two" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Work email"></div><div id="three" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Personal email"></div></div>'
    $('#addelement').append(el);
}
```